# Get AsyncContext from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I'm using Spring's `OncePerRequestFilter` overriding `shouldNotFilterAsyncDispatch` method to return false. This way it can handle asynchronous requests. In the filter I'm trying to do the following:

```
if (isAsyncDispatch(request)) {
    request.getAsyncContext().addListener(new AsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("onComplete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {

        }
    });
}
```

So `isAsyncDispatch` returns true as expected. But when I try `getAsyncContext` it fails with the following exception:

```
IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false)
```

Indeed, `request.isAsyncStarted()` returns false, but `request.isAsyncSupported()` is true and `request.getDispatcherType()` is `ASYNC`.

I don't get: is it async or not? Maybe I'm using the API in a wrong way? How do I add an `AsyncListener`? Maybe it is because I'm using Tomcat?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: AFAIK the request is started for async somewhere in the DispatcherServlet. Or more precisely while processing the actual request mapping method that returns a kind of async result. So if it's the case that this code is in the filter on the pre-request side, the `startAsync()` method was not called yet.

Answer (score 1):

When I have done this in the past, we have done:

```
if (request.isAsyncSupported()) {
      AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
      // Do whatever with context
}
```

The javadoc for `getAsyncContext()` does state: (in [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAsyncContext()))

> IllegalStateException - if this request has not been put into asynchronous mode, i.e., if neither startAsync() nor startAsync(ServletRequest,ServletResponse) has been called

Comment: Thanks, man, now I'm able to ad listener. But it starts asynchronous operation, doesn't it? I have `Future` as a result of an operation in Spring controller. So I assume it is already asynchronous. Also it starts asynchronous processing for other requests as well but I need it only for async controller methods