# It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, serializable

Errors Occurred：

```
{
  "status" : 1,
  "code" : 0,
  "message" : "It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false)",
  "param" : null,
  "data" : null
}
```

Code related to the occurrence of an error:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/cashier/v1")
public class PayController {
    @ApiOperation("pay for shop")
    @GetMapping(value = "/pay")
    public ResponseVO<PayResponseVO> pay(ShopPayRequestVO requestVO, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return payService.pay(requestVO, request);
    }
}


@Service
@Slf4j
public class PayServiceImpl implements IPayService {
    @Override
    public ResponseVO<PayResponseVO> pay(ShopPayRequestVO requestVO, HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthorizationException {
        log.info("pay request param:{}", JSON.toJSONString(requestVO));
        PayResponseVO vo = new PayResponseVO();
        ......
        vo.setOrderNo(businessOrderNo);
        vo.setShopId(requestVO.getShopId());
        log.info("pay response param:{}", JSON.toJSONString(vo));
        return ResponseVO.success(vo);
    }
}

@Data
public class PayResponseVO {

    private Object payInfo;

    private String orderNo;

    private String shopId;
}
```

Single step debugging all code can be executed normally, but the front end still has errors，
I encountered this error, but there is no appropriate solution online. I solved it myself. I share the solution below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get AsyncContext from HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957127/get-asynccontext-from-httpservletrequest)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem in my project:

PayResponseVO. Java class **needs to implement Serializable interface**

```
@Data
public class PayResponseVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7991519952738359328L;

    private Object payInfo;

    private String orderNo;

    private String shopId;
}
```