# How do I handle a Callable in my AOP Around advice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have a controller in my Spring Boot application. In my controller, I have an endpoint where I need to timeout the call if too much time elapses. I do this by returning a `Callable` from this method and including the config `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` in my application.yml. This seems to work well for our purposes.

I also have an Aspect class in this application that contains a method that is triggered whenever a method in my controller is called. The point of this method is to log details such as the amount of time taken for an endpoint, what the response code was, and etc. This works well when the response of the method is not a `Callable` (ie. a `ResponseEntity`) since I can get response information from the return type without issue. However, I cannot get this response information when the method returns a `Callable` without invoking `((Callable) ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed()).call()` from the aspect class. This makes API calls longer, and I believe that's because it invokes `call()` twice. Is there any way that I can get the response information without having to use `call()` in the Aspect class?

Here is a simple example of what I have so far in my aspect class:

```
    @Around("...")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        if (!(result instanceof Callable<?>)) {
            // Do logging using result, which is a ResponseEntity...
        } else {
            Object callableResult = ((Callable<?>) result).call();
            // Do logging using callableResult, which is a ResponseEntity...
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What information are you trying to log from the `callableResult` ? The advise happens in the context of the current thread and from what I have read  , the `Callable` instance is called from another thread to produce the result.

Comment: The `callableResult` is a `ResponseEntity` which I can get response information like response code and information from the response body. I'm wondering if there's a way to handle this logging after the `Callable.call` invocation is made. I tried a point cut using `java.util.concurrent.Callable.call` with no luck though...

Comment: A complete reproducible test case could help others to run the code , debug and share an answer if you want to take the Spring AOP route .You could also explore [async interception](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-async-interception)

Comment: Unless your `Callable` happens to be a Spring bean/component, there is no way to intercept it with Spring AOP. So in this case, you either turn those callables into registered Spring components or you need to use native AspectJ. In order to say more, I need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, though.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation at work a while ago and the following seems to solve it: [Log response body after asynchronous Spring MVC controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945070/log-response-body-after-asynchronous-spring-mvc-controller-method)

Note: Try logging the async response in a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and `implements ResponseBodyAdvice` instead. This should capture the real response instead of callable.

You could have a class annotated with `@Aspects` for logging request and `@ControllerAdvice` for logging response together.

e.g.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdvice;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;


@Aspect
@ControllerAdvice
public class LoggingAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAdvice.class);
    private static final AtomicLong ID = new AtomicLong();

    @Before("within(com.example.demo.controller..*)")
    public void endpointBefore(JoinPoint p) {
        LOGGER.info(p.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + p.getSignature().getName() + " START");
        Object[] signatureArgs = p.getArgs();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        try {
            if (signatureArgs != null && signatureArgs.length > 0) {
                LOGGER.info("\nRequest object: \n" + mapper.writeValueAsString(signatureArgs[0]));
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("request object is empty");
            }
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        long id = ID.incrementAndGet();

        ServletServerHttpResponse responseToUse = (ServletServerHttpResponse) response;
        HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter;
        LoggingHttpOutboundMessageWrapper httpOutputMessage = new LoggingHttpOutboundMessageWrapper();
        try {
            httpMessageConverter = (HttpMessageConverter) selectedConverterType.newInstance();
            httpMessageConverter.write(body, selectedContentType, httpOutputMessage);
            LOGGER.info("response {}, {}, {}, {}, {}", id, responseToUse.getServletResponse().getStatus(), responseToUse.getServletResponse().getContentType(),
                    responseToUse.getHeaders(), httpOutputMessage.getResponseBodyInString());
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return body;
    }

    private static final class LoggingHttpOutboundMessageWrapper implements HttpOutputMessage {
        private HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        @Override
        public OutputStream getBody() throws IOException {
            return byteArrayOutputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
            return httpHeaders;
        }

        public String getResponseBodyInString() {
            return new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        }
    }

}
```